# Como instalar cabeçalhos do phpize

Tags: php

Quando utlizo o phpize no OSX 10.12.4, obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
$ phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:
```

Como instalar os cabeçalhos que estão faltando?

Comment: Depende muito de onde baixou e o processo que fez para baixar o phpize, me parece que você deixou de instalar o PHP primeiro, ou talvez esteja usando Mamp ou Xampp, de qualquer forma acho que isto resolve http://stackoverflow.com/q/19531262/1518921

Answer (score 1):

No OSX para instalar os arquivos da pasta /usr/include é necessário instalar as ferramentas de linha de comando do Xcode, no terminal execute:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```